# Angular2 window open callback

Tags: angular, events, typescript, window, subscribe

I need to open a new window, do some stuff on there and catch when this window is closed from the child.

Here is my "parent" code :

```
let logonWindow = window.open(url, "_blank", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=400,height=400");
logonWindow.onbeforeunload = this.closing;                        
logonWindow.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.closing, true);

private closing(e) {
  window.location.href = this.storage.get<string>("redirectUrl");
  return null;
}
```

My child code :

```
this.http.post(AppSettings.API_BASE + "Login", postData)
.subscribe(res => {

    if (res != null) {
      this.storage.set("token", JSON.parse(res.json()));
      window.close();
    }
  });
```

And it never goes into the "closing" function.

Any idea why ? What can I change to make it work ?